# How to add button cart in shopping cart react redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, shopping-cart

how to add an action when the add button is clicked then the item will display the product?
This code does not display the product when clicked
I've been fiddling with it but it's still an error, who knows, someone here can help me and fix the code and explain it

**cartAction.js**

```
import {ADD_TO_CART} from './ActionType';


export const addToCart = (items) =>{
    return{
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        items     //I'm confused about what to do in the action payload here
    }
}
```

**cartReducer.js**

```
import ImgT from './images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg';
 import {ADD_TO_CART} from './ActionType';

const initState = {
    items: [
        {id:1,title:'title',
         brand:cc',
         images:ImgT,
          desc:'helo world',
          price:125.00}
    ],addItems:[],
    total:0
}

const cartReducer= (state = initState,action)=>{
    if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART){
     return {...state, addItems:state.addItems}   //I'm confused about what to do in the action payload here
    }
      return state

}
export default cartReducer;
```

**cart.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 class Cart extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
    <div>
             {this.props.Items.map(item =>{
                  <div key={item.id}>
                      {/* <img src={item.images} /> */}
                      <p>{item.title}</p>
                      <h4>brand: {item.brand}</h4>
                      <p>{item.price}</p>
                  </div>
          })
        }
    </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapToProps = (state ) =>{
    return{
    Items:state.addItems}
}


export default connect(mapToProps)(Cart);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Cart from './Cart';
import {addToCart} from './cartAction';



class Home extends Component{

    handleClick = () =>{
        this.props.addToCart()
    }
    
    render(){
        let item = this.props.items.map(item =>{
            return(
                <div className='card' key={item}>
                    <img style={{width:'10rem'}} src={item.images}/>
                    <p  className='card-title '>{item.title}</p>
                    <h2 className='card-title fs-4'>{item.brand}</h2>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()} className='btn btn-primary'>Add to cart</button>
                    <h3 className='fs-5'>{item.price}</h3>

                </div>
            )
        })
        
        return(
            <div className="container">
               <h3>Home</h3>
               {item}
                    <Cart/>
            </div>
        )
    }
        
}    
const mapToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        items:state.items,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{ 
        addToCart: () => dispatch(addToCart())}
    
}

export default connect(mapToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @AbdolKarim  there is no error in the console log, but when the add button is clicked the product does not display in the cart

Comment: @AbdolKarim error

Comment: what does that mean?